# Text filled with blurred background image

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a title that has a glass looking visual which blurs the background image.

I was able to do it but I had to make references to the background image 3 times and it doesn't seem very optimal.

Here is the code I used.

```css
body {
  background: blue url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/318/318370.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/318/318370.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  filter: blur(10px);
  background-size: cover;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  //display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.mask {
  background: #fff;
}

#h2 {
  background: url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/318/318370.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-size: cover;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div id="bimage" class="bimage"></div>
  <h2 class="mask">MARIO</h2>
  <h2 id="h2">MARIO</h2>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/marceltoma/pen/zYWGYwp

I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you checked the background-clip property? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip
I haven't used it yet but maybe it is a good case of use! Tell me if you see the way!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codepen, you can start reusing css in many places.

This is just an example for you to get started:

```css
/* Reusing background properties */
#h2, body, .bimage {
  background: url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/318/318370.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Reusing with children selector */
.title, .title * {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: blue 
}

.bimage {
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-family:Verdana;
  //display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.mask {
  background: #fff;
}

#h2 {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div id="bimage" class="bimage"></div>
  <h2 class="mask">MARIO</h2>
  <h2 id="h2">MARIO</h2>
</div>
```

Please give it a try, and keep DRY!